# I'm passing around some functions an element using the "this" keyword and the "call" method

Tags: javascript, this

What I'm trying to do is to pass to a function a determined element which I'm trying to represent with the "this" keyword. The problem is it has to go across two functions and I don't understand where the error is. Everything starts in the 3rd function which then calls the 2nd function passing document.body as what will be considered as the "this" of the function. Then the second function passes "this" to the 1st function with the "call" method.

```
function create_tag(tag, inner) {
    element = document.createElement(tag);
    if (inner) {
        element.innerHTML = inner;
    }
    this.appendChild(element);
    return element;
}

function create_input(label_value) {
    input = create_tag.call(this, "input");
    label = create_tag.call(this, "label", label_value);
    input.setAttribute("id", "pers_" + label_value);
    return input;
}

function crea_personaggio() {
    input_values = ["Name", "Lastname", "Nickname", "Age"];
    for (i = 0; i < input_values.length; i++) {
        create_input.call("document.body", input_values[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You've neglected to declare your local variables with `var` (which means all your variables are global).

Comment: What exactly is not working?  Is there an error message?

Comment: Why don't you just pass the element in as a parameter?

Answer (score 5):

`.call()` requires an object to get passed in as first argument, you're passing in a string instead which definately will not work for you here (it will work technically though).

Just go for

```
create_input.call(document.body, input_values[i]);
```

Beside that, you're ommitting the `var` keyword for any variable declaration which will end up in a chunk of global variables (that might not be a problem here, but its very bad karma).

Comment: +1 Although passing in a string *works* (within the call, `this` will be a `String` object representing that string, the primitive gets promoted). It's just not what he *wants*. ;-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: yeah thats pretty much what I wanted to express. Technically it works.